# Network Programmer Blogs (especially for games)

Tags: networking, tcp, udp

What are some good network programmer blogs?  I'm especially interested in people who write about multiplayer games (MMORPG/RTS/FPS/etc), but any well written blog on the subject would be great.

Here's a good blog I found on another stackoverflow post:
[Glenn Fiedler's Networking for Game Programmers](http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/)
[Gamasutra Blogs](http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/) occasionally has articles covering network programming

PS: I'm interested in reading about anything -- from fundamentals to advanced.  Preferred language is C/C++ but the more language agnostic the better.  There are always gems to pick up for now or later =)

Answer (score 2):

[GameArchitect](http://gamearchitect.net/about/) is in my feed list.

Answer (score 1):

For a "bloggish" page, here GameDev.net has lots of articles to read:
[GameDev.net - Multiplayer and Networking](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/list.asp?categoryid=30)

And here is a game network engine you could look at:
[GNE -- Game Networking Engine](http://www.gillius.org/gne/)